# how to add to baseURL some arguments?

Tags: testing, npm, config, playwright

I'm having a link like `baseURL: 'https://www.aaa.com/CPC/?agentcode=123&hotelcode=123',`
and if i'm using the value from baseURL, it cuts it to `https://www.aaa.com` but I need to navigate to page from baseURL, using the whole URL which I expect, as I understand, baseURL is doing its job and works properly, but anyway I need somehow to add everything what goes after .com part also. How can it be done ?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use [`.goto`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-goto) method, from documentation -

> url  URL to navigate page to. The url should include scheme, e.g. https://. When a baseURL via the context options was provided and the passed URL is a path, it gets merged via the new URL() constructor.#

Example -
You can configure the base URL as below using the global config file `playwright.config.ts`

```
import { PlaywrightTestConfig } from '@playwright/test';
const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  use: {
    baseURL: 'https://www.aaa.com',
    browserName: 'firefox',
    headless: true,
  },
};
export default config;
```

then you can use it a tests like below for navigation -

```
    test.describe('Intent of the Test', () => {
        test('should allow me to add todo items', async ({ page }) => {
           await page.goto('/CPC/?agentcode=123&hotelcode=123');   
        })
   });
```

Comment: really good example, but that's not really what I need, it's actually the same with using full url in goto, not using baseURL. I have more than 200 tests which should be running separately and I think it's not normal to write page.goto in each of them, can't use before hooks for it also because of some other issues :(

Comment: ah, my fault, that's not actually the answer but previously I was using beforeAll, in which page argument is not allowed, didn't see beforeEach one, which actually solved my problem

Comment: glad you figured it out.